# Deploy SpringBoot app to Websphere 8.5.5.8

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere-8

I'm trying to deploy a very basic spring boot app to Websphere 8.5.5.8 (with IBM J6 VM, on Java 1.6.0). The same app works on Glassfish but throws exception on Websphere. I've been trying to follow every guide on the net to get it working but still no avail, could someone please shed some light on what I've got wrong?

**The exception log is as below:**

```
[8/4/16 9:36:52:031 HKT] 00000094 SystemErr     R   com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: Unable to load configuration filesnull
[8/4/16 9:36:52:032 HKT] 00000094 SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:433)null
[8/4/16 9:36:52:032 HKT] 00000094 SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)null
[8/4/16 9:36:52:032 HKT] 00000094 SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)null
[8/4/16 9:36:52:032 HKT] 00000094 SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1382)null
[8/4/16 9:36:52:032 HKT] 00000094 SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)null
[8/4/16 9:36:52:032 HKT] 00000094 SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:971)null
[8/4/16 9:36:52:032 HKT] 00000094 SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)null
[8/4/16 9:36:52:032 HKT] 00000094 SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1379)null
[8/4/16 9:36:52:032 HKT] 00000094 SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2189)null
```

**Websphere version info below:**

```
Installation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product Directory        /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
Version Directory        /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version
DTD Directory            /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version/dtd
Log Directory            /var/ibm/InstallationManager/logs

Product List
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ND                       installed

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                  IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment
Version               8.5.5.8
ID                    ND
Build Level           cf081545.03
Build Date            11/12/15
Package               com.ibm.websphere.ND.v85_8.5.5008.20151112_0939
Architecture          x86-64 (64 bit)
Installed Features    IBM 64-bit WebSphere SDK for Java
                      WebSphere Application Server Full Profile
                      EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules
                      Embeddable EJB container
                      Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters
```

**My POM file:**

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>test-server</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.test.ServletInitializer</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And finally my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   /*public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(ServletInitializer.class, args);
   }*/

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ServletInitializer.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue here looks like your `ServletInitializer` class was compiled with a different version than WebSphere is running on.  According to [this table](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27005002), WAS 8.5.5.8 shipped with with Java 68.

Looking at your pom.xml, you have your `ServletInitializer` building with Java 7:

```
<properties>
    <start-class>com.test.ServletInitializer</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
```

So bump that down to `<java.version>1.6</java.version>` and hopefully that will resolve your issue.

Side note: 
You have a dependency in your pom.xml for Java EE 7, but WebSphere traditional is not EE7 compliant until version 9.0, so I'd recommend you bump your `javaee-api` version down to `6.0`.

Comment: Thanks! My server is actually running on java 6 after looking at your answer, I've downgraded the java version which now gets me another error...I guess this got me to the next stage of my problems...

Comment: oops, misread the table -- WAS 8558 should run on Java 6, not Java 8.  I'll update my answer.